# How to get process which creates sub.sub.sub.sub GET requests

Tags: nginx, get, localhost, subdomain

I'm running a NGINX server (`1.14.0-8.5.3.4~jessie1`) and getting random requests from `127.0.0.1` for sub.sub.sub.subdomains that each are existing.

```
2018/09/01 11:06:35 [error] 43030#43030: *799005 open() "/var/www
/roundcube.owncloud.seafile.owncloud.*****.onion" failed
(2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: ****.org,
request: "GET     /roundcube.owncloud.seafile.owncloud.****.onion
HTTP/1.1", host: "roundcube.owncloud.seafile.owncloud.****.onion",
referrer: "https://roundcube.owncloud.seafile.owncloud.****.onion/"
```

As you can see the length and number of subdomains and time of request is varied randomly.

```
2018/09/01 11:06:47 [error] 43030#43030: *799058 open() "/var/www
/seafile.owncloud.seafile.pad.roundcube.pad.roundcube.seafile.seafile.
pad.roundcube.roundcube.owncloud.pad.roundcube.owncloud.pad.pad.seafile.
roundcube.roundcube.owncloud.*****.onion" failed (2: No such 
file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: *****.org, request: "GET 
/seafile.owncloud.seafile.pad.roundcube.pad.roundcube.seafile.seafile.pad.
roundcube.roundcube.owncloud.pad.roundcube.owncloud.pad.pad.seafile.
roundcube.roundcube.owncloud.*****.onion HTTP/1.1", host: 
"seafile.owncloud.seafile.pad.roundcube.pad.roundcube.seafile.seafile.
pad.roundcube.roundcube.owncloud.pad.roundcube.owncloud.pad.pad.seafile.
roundcube.roundcube.owncloud.*****.onion"
```

How can I get the process which is creating this mess ?

There is no cron job running.

Comment: `.onion` URLs should be related to Tor. Do you have it locally or a Firefox enabled with it?

Comment: At the server the tor service is running to provide onion adresses. Nginx handles them without problems (they are reachable via tor). No at the server no firefox is running.